# react-native background color below app / view

Tags: react-native

There is a white area on larger phones (not present on SE for example) below my application, it is a bleed area I believe, and it is white, I would like to color this area in my app, is this possible? I have seen some posts that this must be done in xcode, but I wanted to confirm that, my current build chain doesn't touch xcode and is entirely in expo.

Comment: white area ? you are using correctly flex ?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot?